# Why didn't Dwight ever suspect Creed of something nefarious?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

I know this is a comedy, but Creed said and did very suspicious things throughout the series. He also made allusions to a shady history. Should Dwight not have fixated on Creed as he did with nearly everyone else in the office?

Comment: He says and does some very odd things, but in general, is harmless. I think Dwight shares this opinion.

Comment: and Dwight wasn't exactly smart. I mean his hero was Michael...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Because Dwight can't see what's right in front of him.** That's one of the ironic things that are amusing about Dwight, and his lack of common sense is preventing him from putting these particular two and two together. It's also why he keeps falling for Jim and Pam's pranks; you would expect a true paranoid to be a little less gullible.

Consider the season 2 episode [The Secret](http://theoffice.wikia.com/wiki/The_Secret), where Dwight explains to the camera about telltale signs that a person is lying. But in a later scene, when Michael (who's a horrible liar) lies to Dwight while displaying *every sign* on Dwight's list, Dwight surmises that he's telling the truth. Simply put, Dwight might *think* he's insightful, but he really isn't.

A similar technique was employed in another Greg Daniels show, *King of the Hill*, with the character of [Dale Gribble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale_Gribble). A paranoid conspiracy theorist, Dale suspects everything and everyone, but is somehow unaware that his wife has been cheating on him for years with Native American friend John Redcorn and that his son is really Redcorn's son - even though it's all *extremely* obvious and *everyone else* in town knows about it.

It's also worth mentioning that Dwight thinks very little of his co-workers, and actively seeks them out mainly if they 1. mess with him (like Jim and Pam always do) or 2. threaten his work status and relationship with Michael (like Andy did). And since Creed is not really one for pranks and for the most part has *zero* ambition at work, he's just not on Dwight's radar.

Comment: "Jim is my enemy. But it turns out that Jim is also his own worst enemy. And the enemy of my enemy is my friend. So Jim, is actually my friend. But, because he is his own worst enemy, the enemy of my friend is my enemy so actually Jim is my enemy. But-"

Comment: "It's also worth mentioning that Dwight thinks very little of his co-workers, and actively seeks them out mainly if they 1. mess with him (like Jim and Pam always do) or 2. threaten his work status and relationship with Michael (like Andy did)" - I would add a third category, If he feels they are cheating somehow. In "The Meeting" of Season 6, but Dwight and Toby went over to Darryl's house to catch him in faking an injury only to insult Darryl's sister and nullify their correct suspicion. In this third category, we could find something Creed does that should set Dwight off.

Comment: And in the episode I mentioned, he does the same with Oscar and actually catches him faking the flu. So he does get it right on rare occasions, but so does a broken clock. ;) And the thing is, Creed doesn't really do much. I think he just has to do some brief checkup every week or so and that about sums up his "quabity ashwunz" chores.

Comment: Dwight sort of _acknowledged_ that he is liable to miss obvious things, when he quickly started doubting himself when "asian Jim" claimed that he has always been asian Jim. Jim's prank worked specifically on the premise that Dwight knows that he can miss obvious things, thus causing Dwight to second guess himself. If Dwight didn't think of himself as someone who misses obvious things, Dwight would've refused to acknowledge asian Jim as Jim.

Comment: @keepaustinbeard: Creed is quite bad at hiding his misdeeds. It's possible that Dwight has already targeted Creed and has been reprimanded for it _before_ the show began. Neither Dwight nor Creed were new employees at the start of the show.